# Line 1 is not working, are not the same these two lines? why?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scripting, zenity

I hope you can help me with this problem ...
I have in following piece of code:

```
i=1
COMMAND="echo "$((i*19))"; sleep 1; i=$((i+1))"
```

I have no idea why this line does not work: (Call line 1)

```
($COMMAND; $COMMAND; $COMMAND; $COMMAND) | zenity --progress --text="BAR PROGRESS!!" --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

I also tried with:

```
($((COMMAND)); $((COMMAND)); $((COMMAND)); $((COMMAND))) | zenity --progress --text="BAR PROGRESS!!" --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

And this line if it works: (call line 2)

```
(echo "$((i*19))"; sleep 1; i=$((i+1)); echo "$((i*19))"; sleep 1; i=$((i+1)); echo "$((i*19))"; sleep 1; i=$((i+1)); echo "$((i*19))"; sleep 1; i=$((i+1))) | zenity --progress --text="BAR PROGRESS!!" --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

They are not supposed to be the same ?? (Line 1 and linea2)

What I do is instead of putting put Line 1 Line 2, but is very sloppy and that's why I want to use the line 1 (which has more neat and understandable syntax)

Thank you!!

Comment: Any reason not to use a standard `for` loop?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i not occurred to me, as you say of it?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `for` loop instead of attempting to evaluate a string as a command:

```
for i in {1..4}; do
    echo $(( i * 19 ))
    sleep 1
done | zenity --progress --text="BAR PROGRESS!!" --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and it was what I needed, thank you very much !!

Comment: Is there any way in that window zenity say: "Missing x seconds for the progress bar is full" ??
And the variable x will diminish by 1 for every second that passes

Comment: I don't really know anything about zenity, sorry. I thought your main question was about shell scripting.